# Load the different .txt file with each other in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 1000 txt file, each of them has the contain a 2x5 matrix of values. I want to load all of them with one loop.

And finally, build one matrix of size 2000x5.

The names of the files are: A_1, A_2, ..., A_1000.

Could you help me with how to load all of them with each other?
I have tried as follows, but it could not solve my problem.

```
for i in range(1001):
    filename = 'A%s.txt'%i

    P =  np.loadtxt(r"filename")
```

Comment: I want a matrix

Comment: I don't know why I can not edit it. The size of the matrix which I want is 2000 * 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.zeros((2000, 5))
for idx in range(1000):
    f = f'A_{idx+1}.txt'
    vals = np.loadtxt(f)  # shape 2x5
    X[2 * idx:2 * (idx + 1), :] = vals
```

If the text file have some special delimiter you can add the following argument `delimiter=<DELIMITER>` to `np.loadtxt`

Comment: Thank you so much. One little question. I have to write the code in jupyter, my file is in folder for example D. So here when I use the ```np.loadtxt(f)```, it can not work. I have to use np.loadtxt(r"C\f") and it says that there Is no anything. However when I upload the file in jupyter the above code works. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate on the structure of the files and location relative to the notebook

Comment: Yes. for the line ```vals = np.loadtxt(f)```, if the location of my .txt file are in drive C in Afile folder, I have to use a code like this``` vals= np.loadtxt(r"C\Afile\??")```, I don't know how I load the A_1, A_2, A_3, A_1000 matrixes. I have to use the jupyter.

Comment: So in that case, if all of them is in the same dir you can create a string of the location, lets say `p = r'C:/AFiles/'` and add it to `f` like `f'{p}A_{idx+1}.txt'`. But validate that you can see the files in `p` using `os.listdir(p)` or something